# Post a reference type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view (`IEnumerable<Client>`) and I need to post a client to action.

Using:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Client client)
```

When I use `@Html.TextBox("Client.Name")` and post it, in my action I receive a client object with all properties null.

When I use `@Html.TextBox("Name")` and post it, in my action I receive a null.

### How can I do this?

Well... I reopen my solution and it works with '@Html.TextBox("Name");'... magic..

Comment: Is the textbox inside the form-tags? Maybe a sample of your markup. Does client have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yes it is inside, and client has no constructor.

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to see more of your view.

Comment: I suspect a caching issue. Anyway, the second way is correct; you give the helper the property name, without the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Model Binding in ASP.NET MVC you should use the property name of the model without the class name for input elements. So it should be `@Html.TextBox("Name")` and not `@Html.TextBox("Client.Name")`.

Suppose you have a reference type property(ReferenceTypeProperty) in the Client class and you want to map a property(Member) of that on submitting then you should use `@Html.TextBox("ReferenceTypeProperty.Member")`.